# Onclick button disables checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

. .I couldn't find a proper answer for onclick function on a button disables three checkboxes. . .

```
<input id="option" name="item_number" type="checkbox" class="ckbox" value="1" onclick="this.checked=!this.checked;"/>
<input id="option" name="item_number" type="checkbox" class="ckbox" value="1" onclick="this.checked=!this.checked;"/>
<input id="option" name="item_number" type="checkbox" class="ckbox" value="1" onclick="this.checked=!this.checked;"/>
```

And the button to add onclick function already there are many onclick functions.

```
<input type="button" class="button2" id="item2" value="Add to Cart" Title="Add to Cart" onClick="addItem_check('item_listing_100','ItemTable','100','Amul Butter','500','g','150.00','1','kg','200.00','2','kg','250.00'); amul1.style.backgroundColor='#c2ed5c'; if(this.value=='Add to Cart') {this.value = 'Remove from Cart'}; item2();"/>
```

So please give me a solution guys

Comment: **id** must be unique.. And what does the functions `addItem_check` and `item2` do?

Comment: Rohan addItem_check adds the item to a cart, and item2 i am working on the checkbox disabling function. . so far not good

Comment: How exactly is `onclick="this.checked=!this.checked;"` helpful in anything?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with what you are trying to do is you have the same `id="option"` for all three checkboxes. They need to be unique.

You can do the following:

```
<input id="option1" name="item_number" type="checkbox" class="ckbox" value="1" onclick="this.checked=!this.checked;"/>
<input id="option2" name="item_number" type="checkbox" class="ckbox" value="1" onclick="this.checked=!this.checked;"/>
<input id="option3" name="item_number" type="checkbox" class="ckbox" value="1" onclick="this.checked=!this.checked;"/>
```

In Javascript:

```
$(function(){
  $('#button1').click(function(){
       for(var i=1;i<=3;i++)
           $('#option'+i).prop('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that:

```
    $(function(){
        $('#button1').click(function(){
        $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled','true');
        });
   });
```

Comment: You must use **prop()** instead of **attr()**

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 $(function(){
        $('#button1').click(function(){
        $('.ckbox').prop('disabled','true');
        });
   });
```

Comment: You must use **prop()** instead of **attr()**

Answer (score 0):

Try with this to disable check boxes by clicking on button.

'item2' is id of button & 'ckbox' is class of check box as per your example.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#item2").click(function(){
        $(".ckbox").attr("disabled","disabled");
    });
});
```